# passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

Tags: php, symfony

So I am having a form where I want to use an EntityType field for the entity "Einzelteil". Unfortunately I keep on getting the same error "...passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?"
I do not see anyhwere in my code where I would initialize an object. In the form I just call a function to get all available "entities". Can someone explain to me how a getAll function could cause this issue?

Here is the form:

```
 public function __construct(ArtikelEinzelteilRepository $artikelEinzelteilRepository, EinzelteilRepository $einzelteilRepository)
{
    $this->artikelEinzelteilRepository = $artikelEinzelteilRepository;
    $this->einzelteilRepository = $einzelteilRepository;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('einzelTeil', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'class' => Einzelteil::class,
            'choice_label' => function (Einzelteil $einzelteil) {
                return sprintf('(%d) %s', $einzelteil->getEinzelteilName(), $einzelteil->getEinzelteilNumber());
            },
            'choices' => $this->einzelteilRepository->getAll(),
            'placeholder' => 'Wähle ein Einzelteil aus',
            'invalid_message' => 'Hat nicht funktioniert',
            'multiple' => true,
            'disabled' => false,
        ])
        ->add('artikelEinzelteilMenge', NumberType::class,
            ['label' => false])
        ->add('Speichern', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn--red']
        ]);

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'artikelId' => null,
        'data_class' => ArtikelEinzelteil::class,
        'mapped' => false]);
}
```

When I load the website I keep on getting the above mentioned error.

Here is the Code for the entity Einzelteil:

```
/**
 * Einzelteil
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="einzelteil")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Einzelteil
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $einzelteilId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $einzelteilName = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_number", type="string", length=50, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $einzelteilNumber = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_description", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $einzelteilDescription = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_specification", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $einzelteilSpecification = '';

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_search_terms", type="json")
     */
    private $einzelteilSearchTerms = [];


    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_active", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $einzelteilActive = true;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="einzelteil_timestamp", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="current_timestamp()"})
     */
    private $einzelteilTimestamp = 'current_timestamp()';

    /**
     * Einzelteil constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->einzelteilTimestamp =\DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s",date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getEinzelteilId(): int
    {
        return $this->einzelteilId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $einzelteilId
     */
    public function setEinzelteilId(int $einzelteilId): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilId = $einzelteilId;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEinzelteilName(): string
    {
        return $this->einzelteilName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $einzelteilName
     */
    public function setEinzelteilName(string $einzelteilName): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilName = $einzelteilName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEinzelteilNumber(): string
    {
        return $this->einzelteilNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $einzelteilNumber
     */
    public function setEinzelteilNumber(string $einzelteilNumber): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilNumber = $einzelteilNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEinzelteilDescription(): string
    {
        return $this->einzelteilDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $einzelteilDescription
     */
    public function setEinzelteilDescription(string $einzelteilDescription): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilDescription = $einzelteilDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEinzelteilSpecification(): string
    {
        return $this->einzelteilSpecification;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $einzelteilSpecification
     */
    public function setEinzelteilSpecification(string $einzelteilSpecification): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilSpecification = $einzelteilSpecification;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEinzelteilSearchTerms(): array
    {
        $einzelteilSearchTerms = $this->einzelteilSearchTerms;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        //einzelteilSearchTerms[] = 'TERMS';

        return array_unique($einzelteilSearchTerms);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $einzelteilSearchTerms
     */
    public function setEinzelteilSearchTerms(array $einzelteilSearchTerms): self
    {
        $this->einzelteilSearchTerms = $einzelteilSearchTerms;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEinzelteilActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->einzelteilActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $einzelteilActive
     */
    public function setEinzelteilActive(bool $einzelteilActive): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilActive = $einzelteilActive;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEinzelteilTimestamp(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->einzelteilTimestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $einzelteilTimestamp
     */
    public function setEinzelteilTimestamp(\DateTime $einzelteilTimestamp): void
    {
        $this->einzelteilTimestamp = $einzelteilTimestamp;
    }
```

So I look everywhere including here for a possible solution but cannot find anything that would help me. What I tried so far:

- adding persist to the entity ORM Mapping
- setting mapped to false
- setting dataclass to null

In the end I reverted everything as I do not even understand how this error occurs.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Code for ArtikelEinzelteil

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ArtikelEinzelteil
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="artikel_teile", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="artikel_teile_artikel", columns={"artikel_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="artikel_teile_einzelteil", columns={"einzelteil_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArtikelEinzelteil
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artikel_teile_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $artikelTeileId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artikel_teile_menge", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $artikelTeileMenge = 0;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artikel_teile_timestamp", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="current_timestamp()"})
     */
    private $artikelTeileTimestamp = 'current_timestamp()';

    /**
     * @var \Artikel
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artikel")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artikel_id", referencedColumnName="artikel_id")
     * })
     */
    private $artikel;

    /**
     * @var \Einzelteil
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\MLT\Einzelteil\Entity\Einzelteil")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="einzelteil_id", referencedColumnName="einzelteil_id")
     * })
     */
    private $einzelteil;

    /**
     * ArtikelEinzelteil constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->artikelTeileTimestamp =\DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s",date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getArtikelEinzelteilId(): int
    {
        return $this->artikelTeileId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $artikelTeileId
     */
    public function setArtikelEinzelteilId(int $artikelTeileId): void
    {
        $this->artikelTeileId = $artikelTeileId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getArtikelEinzelteilMenge(): int
    {
        return $this->artikelTeileMenge;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $artikelTeileMenge
     */
    public function setArtikelEinzelteilMenge(int $artikelTeileMenge): void
    {
        $this->artikelTeileMenge = $artikelTeileMenge;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getArtikelEinzelteilTimestamp(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->artikelTeileTimestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $artikelTeileTimestamp
     */
    public function setArtikelEinzelteilTimestamp(\DateTime $artikelTeileTimestamp): void
    {
        $this->artikelTeileTimestamp = $artikelTeileTimestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Artikel
     */
    public function getArtikel(): Artikel
    {
        return $this->artikel;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Artikel $artikel
     */
    public function setArtikel(Artikel $artikel): void
    {
        $this->artikel = $artikel;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Einzelteil
     */
    public function getEinzelteil(): Einzelteil
    {
        return $this->einzelteil;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Einzelteil $einzelteil
     */
    public function setEinzelteil(Einzelteil $einzelteil): void
    {
        $this->einzelteil = $einzelteil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of ArtikelEinzelteil. Einzelteil looks good to me.

Comment: thank you for taking a look. I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

So after breaking my head and going through various forums. I found a comment of someone that made me realize my mistake.
My issue was the entity manager. I am working with 2 databases 2 entities and 2 entity managers. One of my entities was using the default one. After injecting the right one in the service class, it worked.